# Why is my unity app crashing when I start another one?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, htc-vive, steamvr

I'm trying to create a multiplayer scene with VR in Unity using a HTC Vive and steamVR. But I can't test my app on a single computer. I do a "build and run" then my app start but when I click on play in the unity interface, the built app crashes. I don't why. I observed that this phenomenon exists when I add the [CameraRig] prefab from the Steam VR plugin which is essential for the VR

Could you help me please ?

Thank you